# Custom UIPrintInteractionController window on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, printing, customization

has anyone succeeded in customizing the window of the `UIPrintInteractionController`. I mean the little window that pops out, when you want to print a file and you can choose the printer, the number of documents etc.

I would like to customize the title, or the looks in general.... is that possible at all?

Thanks in advance!